# Typescript: converting type of array of classes to type of array of constructed classes

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics, typescript-class

there is a problem I've been struggling to solve for quite a time.

I have a function, inside which I put two arguments:

- **classes** - array of classes
- **mapper** - function that takes an array of instances of these classes.

Imagine the function like this:

```
const MapClasses = (classes, mapper) => {
  const instances = classes.map((item) => new item())
  return mapper(instances)
}
```

How could I create a typescript declaration for this, to ensure that **mapper** will always accept an array of instances of **classes**.

Example usage:

```
class Coords {
  x = 10
  y = 10
}

class Names {
  name = 'Some Name'
}

const mapper = ([coords, names]) => {
  return {
    x: coords.x,
    y: coords.y,
    myName: names.name,
  }
}

const mapped = MapClasses([Coords, Names], mapper)
// { x: 10, y: 10, myName: 'Some Name'}
```

So I think it should be possible, to check if mapper is accessing the right values.

I've got it working kinda this way:

```
type MapClasses = <Classes, Mapped>(
  classes: {
    [Property in keyof Classes]: new () => Classes[Property]
  },
  mapper: (instances: Classes) => Mapped,
) => Mapped
```

However in this case, errors show only on **classes** parameter, not the **mapper**.

So is there any way to turn this behaviour around?
....

I will be thankful for any ideas.

Have a nice day.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what you're trying to do, but I suspect you'll be able to accomplish what you're trying to do with built-ins like `Array.prototype.map`. TS will throw up a lot of walls if it looks like you're trying to operate on a raw class rather than an instance.

Can you add more detail on what your solution is for?

Comment: Is [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mAvEQW) what you're looking for?  It would be helpful if your question had a [mre] of the actual problem you're trying to solve (i.e., the error being on `classes` instead of `mapper`); could you [edit] that in?  If my solution works for you I can write up an answer; if not, please let me know what I'm missing.

Comment: @jcalz exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be clear, your problem is that when you call `MapClasses()` incorrectly, the error appears on the `classes` parameter and not on the `mapper` parameter:

```
MapClasses([Names, Coords], mapper) // error
// -------> ~~~~~  ~~~~~~ <---
// |                          |
// |  Type 'typeof Coords' is not assignable to type 'new () => Names'.
// Type 'typeof Names' is not assignable to type 'new () => Coords',
```

This isn't *wrong*, but you would prefer it to happen the other way, like this:

```
MapClasses([Names, Coords], mapper) // error
// -----------------------> ~~~~~~
// Type '[Names, Coords]' is not assignable to type '[Coords, Names]'.
```

---

In order to get this to happen, we need to change the signature of `MapClasses` so that the [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter is inferred from `classes` and not from `mapper`.  This means we need `classes` to have a higher priority *inference site* for the type parameter than `mapper` does.  The details of how the compiler chooses which values to infer types from are not really documented anywhere official; there is a [section of the outdated TypeScript spec](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/3821ef011ada48c14e07e3124c6502a44a3e3856/doc/spec-ARCHIVED.md#3117-type-inference) that goes over what it used to be at some time, though.  A good rule of thumb is that the compiler will choose the value which is related to the type parameter in the "simplest" way.

So we need to refactor the call signature so that the type annotation for `classes` is related to the type parameter more simply than the type annotation for `mapper` is.  Here's one way to do it:

```
const MapClasses = <C extends (new () => any)[], M>(
    classes: [...C],
    mapper: (instances: ElementInstanceType<C>) => M,
): M => {
    const instances = classes.map((item) => new item()) as
        ElementInstanceType<C>;
    return mapper(instances)
}

type ElementInstanceType<C> =
    { [K in keyof C]: C[K] extends new () => infer R ? R : never };
```

The type parameter `C` is the one we are concerned with, and I have [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) it to be an array of [construct signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures).  Conceptually `classes` is just of type `C`, although I have written `[...C]` using a [variadic tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) to give the compiler a hint that we would like to infer `classes` as a tuple and not as an unordered array.

Meanwhile `mapper` is of type `(instance: ElementInstanceType<C>) => M`, where `ElementInstanceType` is a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) whose properties are [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html).  It turns a tuple of construct signature types into a tuple of their corresponding instance types.  Compare `[...C]` to `(instance: ElementInstanceType<C>) => M` and you can see that the former is more simply related to `C` than the latter.

And that means when you call `MapClasses`, the type parameter `C` will tend to be inferred from `classes` and just *checked* against `mapper`.

---

Let's make sure it works.  First of all we need to see that the non-error case still results in a value of the right type:

```
const mapped = MapClasses([Coords, Names], mapper) // okay
// const mapped: { x: number; y: number;  myName: string; }
```

Now we should see what happens when there's an error:

```
MapClasses([Names, Coords], mapper) // error
// -----------------------> ~~~~~~
// Type '[Names, Coords]' is not assignable to type '[Coords, Names]'.
```

And yes, that's what we wanted to see.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKFBcE8AcFMAICiAbWBbWA7cBJTBncAQ0wGNYAVGWAHgGEA+eAXlHnfgG94BtAaXgBLTPADWsSAHsAZvDoBdAFxz+8+LAAe4LABN88TLADu8ABQBKFk2HTYAJ3gAleAH4n8ZYYBu9+AF8AblBQUkkCcHgAWSJoOmQifHxYfWZ4enUtXX1TQxMLK3gSSHMeeQAaKIZTNg5SeMTk5R4AOlaFMpr2NBi4O2VTYUIScnxlFHQsXHDhymp6BktmJkiOkHNlSILOTvhQ8KFpsmSWXfqk-Gbu6FMB7TRFplyhO4tLBJ2OJFQMbDwho6ocHmQRAnzssHAAFc7CIrr0BocRuZQH5giA9oQojE4glzgB5OyCADmJ2isTOxwShUwkEK+noFUiVR2dVxjS4Hw4-AOYgkMjkSgMxjMDxUfHkOz8q0+cPs-UGxCOozkopWoFVaLRrMSckkkjseg5oI4GhOAEYAAw7WmpS0orVneAAOSIGH022N7EwroQqQA5ABlSQYZ0+v32sDosKY2UOVKmHihfV6Cret2Cnh0PUG-AVF3p0UesEQ6EiIufE3KJM55oaaUV9iQKvZvTNSD1htoSD52CeH0XNOwDv+CNa6MRWU6UnYin4BNZ5O50PpiqxywAenX8EkoiIkFAm924-gk+U3A0nkhaAARvYAvAmwYr7e7PeT92fcpCITMET76jIzJHEGnwAliQTHslwXHNyhPHp7A3Ld7DsfUDy3ABaTCsOw9CmAAPwIgj2EIwi0iwtD4AAHwbGjaLoyiKOo+BAQQP0oDgfloL0P0hH0TBJAiXFiW9a9UHgcBJHE6h4D9J58iWZdkj9ZoKJYmT2NgflIJ4wQ+IEul8GEohRIQCSpLgGS5NFLj8D9VZQCA2cIP7CobNgtd4EPZDUJAQ8cP8gKcPwki8NU6S-R4SDXJbfB5B0vTBMSIyTPEySNJkzMYrzfs4pUyMdFgVlwSPfYLy4Qov3AH8SUCUACqKhAMQiUh+i8IhkDPCr4G-YQatFLxJEEHQQXq+Jiqak9OqISrqtKfwQTqwqxoQaRITIcBBDCeBpBoAANKoyt2ioWrMNqOvgXb+sGnRV067lhF5KRZF2wVdtUOa-HWeABqGkFpFMOtdlXcwAiAA)